# Java static variables that depend upon each other

Tags: java, static

There are two classes, each with it's own static field. What will happen when one field depends on another? For example:

```
public class A {
    public final static Something something = new Something(B.needed);
}

public class B {
    public final static Needed needed = new Needed();
}
```

Test I made suggest that in that case `needed` will be initialized before `something`. In test I was asking Java for variable of class `A` and `B` wasn't loaded before. However, result may be just coincidence. Is there any mechanism in Java that will guarantee me that `needed` will always initialize to be used as argument?

I made another test. Results also show that in extreme cases final primitive types have default value (so they actually have different values in different places of code, despite being final):

```
public class A {
    public final static int test = 3 - B.test;
}

public class B {
    public final static int test = 2 - A.test;
}
```

If you run test in a way that loads class `A` first, values will be:

```
A.test = 1
B.test = 2
```

Then if you run test with `B` loading first, values will be:

```
A.test = 3
B.test = -1
```

It seems that Java simply uses default `int` value `0`. I was surprised that this code compiles.

Results of second test also suggest that Java tries to initialize static field it's planning to use when initializing variable from other class. Is this correct? Is it documented, predictable behavior?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2 for lots of details

Comment: possible duplicate of [What if a static initializer in class X invokes a method in Y, but Y's static initializers invoke a method in X to set up its static values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971407/what-if-a-static-initializer-in-class-x-invokes-a-method-in-y-but-ys-static-in)

Comment: be careful - such dependencies sometime result in maintainability loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you have tree-like dependencies of your classes, you can rely on class X having been initialized when class Y needs it. As soon as you introduce loops (class X needs Y and Y needs X, or even A needs B which needs C which needs D which needs A), behaviour is undefined, and may change whenever you change your java version, JVM vendor, hardware platform or whatever. Don't do that - circular dependencies are almost always the result of bad planning.